Api for historical data like volumes and marketcap
Can anyone suggest better api models to get historical data of volumes, marketcap and prices over 15 days period?

I got a solution with birdeye api https://docs.birdeye.so/reference/get_defi-ohlcv, feel free to response if someone has better solution
